# adding admob jar file and class not found error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, admob

I am trying to add admob.jar file but no success. I follow all steps like, right click project file choose, properties, choose build path, add external jar file, and click order and export, select GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1 jar and click OK. However my admob.jar file copied into Referenced Libraries not to Libs folder. I did copy paste physically to libs folder but  I did not work. Also I am receving following error. I am using ADT tool and My OS is windows vista . Also All my folders and files are saved at same place. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally I copy the jar file in my libs folder, then I refresh the view on Eclipse (press F5, to make the file appears under libs). Then you can just right-click on the file, select "Build Path" and click "Add to Build Path".

It seems you didn't refresh the view there.

A small note, the new way of adding Admob is by using Google Play Services SDK method (https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html?hl=fr)

Comment: wow,I can see my file at my libs folder thanks  but same time it also at Referenced Library and Private library. But I have same error message :( Source not found.. Anything Do I need to do?

Comment: The source not found error is not bad, it means that you did not load the source library for the admob SDK, which is the right think to do. (I think the source is not available anyway). Keep going in integrating the SDK into your app.

Comment: sorry I am not good programmer and new android what you mean keep integrating the SDK. keep update files or download another files.  I think I missing something but did know what is it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Google play service sdk for Add mobs rather than jar.

here is the example to use it like this:
calling like this:

```
 LoadAdViewInEveryActivity.loadAdds(this, mAddMobsLinearLayout);
```

here is the class:

```
public class LoadAdViewInEveryActivity
{
    private static AdView adView = null;

    public static void loadAdds(Activity act, LinearLayout adLayout)
    {
        adLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        adView = new AdView(act);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(Constant.AD_UNIT_ID);

        AdRequest.Builder adRequestBuilder = new AdRequest.Builder();
        adRequestBuilder.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR);
        adLayout.addView(adView);
        adView.loadAd(adRequestBuilder.build());
    }

    public static void destroyView()
    {
        if (adView != null)
        {
            adView.destroy();
            adView = null;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Sorry I am new on android and programming. Should I add this class into do my mainactivity.class or do I need to create a new class. Is there any tutorial I can use. Thanks

Comment: No just make a class in your main package and called this activity where you want to show the add.